# Grails criteria in case insensitive

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to do a case insensitive `in` clause in Grails?

I have this:

```
"in"("name", filters.tags)
```

and I want it to ignore case. I guess I could do a sqlRestriction and do something like `UPPER(name) in (commaSeparatedFilterTags)` and take the list of filter tags and create a comma separated list where they are all uppercased, but was wondering if there's an easier/better way?

Answer (score 4):

yes you could use

```
def commaSeparatedFilterTags = "'name 1','NAME 2','namE 3',...,'name N'"
DomainClass.createCriteria().list{
    sqlRestriction ("upper(name) in (${commaSeparatedFilterTags.toUpperCase()})")
}
```

or use a loop into the criteria

```
def filterTags=["name 1","NAME 2","namE 3",...,"name N"]
DomainClass.createCriteria().list{
    or{
           filterTags.each{                   
            eq("name",it,[ignoreCase: true])
           }
      }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Isn't the loop expensive in terms of CPU or not-performant if I have much data?

Comment: yes It is,  but many databases truncate long data when you try to use an "in" criteria, and it is easier for database to resolve.